# How can i write the results of SAS fullstimer option to a dataset?

Tags: sas

We are evaluating the time taken for two set of codes in SAS. Is there a way we can write/ tabulate option fullstimer results in a SAS dataset, without copying the entire log file into a notepad?

Answer (score 1):

I would go about it like this.

1. Create separate SAS program files containing your code for each approach. Include `options fullstimer` at the top of both.
2. Batch submit your programs and write the logs to permanent files using the `-log` command line option.
3. Create a simple program that reads in both logs and compares the results.

The last step can be accomplished by using data steps with the INFILE statement and restricting the input records to those which are standard output from FULLSTIMER. Then you can compare the created datasets however you wish, e.g. via PROC COMPARE.

Answer (score 0):

SAS has provided a log parsing macro that looks as though it should do the sort of thing that you want. It's available here:

http://support.sas.com/kb/34/301.html